# Reading a single value from Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been dying because of this problem.

Let me show you my **Swift code** first:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneTextField: UITextField!

var dbRef : DatabaseReference!
dbRef = Database.database().reference()

if let text = phoneTextField.text, !text.isEmpty {
    dbRef.child("user").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) {    
        (snapshot) in
        let phoneDB = snapshot.value as? String
        self.testLabel.text = phoneDB
    }
}
```

and this is my **Firebase database**:

```
project-2ac-33
 -user
   -name : "user1"
   -phone : 1111
   -password : 1234
```

What I want to do is: 
if I type any number in the `phoneTextField` 
then `testLabel` shows me `1111` (real phone value in Firebase).

But when I run this project, `testLabel` shows me `user1` instead (value from Firebase) not a phone value.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
...
dbRef.child("user/phone").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
    (snapshot) in
    if let phoneDB = snapshot.value as? Int {
        self.testLabel.text = "\(phoneDB)"
    }
}
```

You were reading *all* `user` children, which also includes the `password` and `name` nodes. The above code reads *only* the desired `user/phone` value instead ;)

Also note that I'm now using `.value` instead of `.childAdded` as well.

Comment: It's working... you save my life... Thank you so much ;)

Comment: One more.... output looks Optional(1234). Can I get any clue that solves this problem?

Comment: Working perfectly! I appreciate again ;)